# TFS Integration Platform conflict on missing changeset

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I'm trying to migrate a project from TFS 2010 into Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) using TFS Integration Platform. I created a new empty project in Team Services and run the migration, however it fails with the following conflict:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.ChangesetNotFoundException:
>   TF14019: The changeset 2466 does not exist. --->
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: TF14019: The changeset
>   2466 does not exist.

However, changeset 2466 does exist in the source collection. The files in the changeset are the default TFS BuildProcessTemplate files commit and I think it has a problem with the UpgradeTemplate.xaml file because it exists in both the source and target project. However when I do a diff on the files there are no differences.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Are there any other solutions to migrating to Team Services which I should try?
I tried the OpsHub free utility but it ran into a problem with duplicate users in the source.

Thanks,
Canice.

Comment: You can try resolvig the checkin manually and then configure the Integration Platform to continue from the next checkin. Or wait until Microsoft releases it's high fidelity import functionality announced at the Build conference last week. It will support uploading your collection DB into VSTS and have it processed on their end. 

It also helps to destroy all contents in the VSTS project prior to starting the migration. You can always check in the process templates again after the migration succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the BuildProcess Template from Migration.

> To exclude an item from migration use the 'clocked' option in the GUI
>   on the initial selection.
>
> or Simply in the XML set Neglect to True for the item you want to
>   exclude:

```
<FilterPair Neglect="true">            
<FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="24d8e37a-e7f9-493d-97ba-c7e5aba96bc6" FilterString="$/SourceProj/BuildProcessTemplates" MergeScope="$/SourceProj/BuildProcessTemplates" />           
<FilterItem MigrationSourceUniqueId="9f1f2df0-6aed-4141-8b6b-26b67d4b8990" FilterString="$/DestinitionProj/BuildProcessTemplates" MergeScope="$/DestinitionProj/BuildProcessTemplates" />         
</FilterPair>
```

Please refer to this link for details: [TFS Integration Application | Cannot Copy Version Control From TFS2010 To TFS2010 -> VC namespace conflict](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7714b3b5-218a-4bdf-a3ca-9b92f5b3ea5a/tfs-integration-application-cannot-copy-version-control-from-tfs2010-to-tfs2010-vc-namespace?forum=tfsintegration)